# how to calculate the area of ​the painted circle?

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, euclidean-geometry

The problem begins by saying that it is a square with side $a$ and ...blah blah blah. They ask me for the area of ​​the small circle but I cannot find its radius.

[image]

manage to find that the radius of the larger circle is
$$\frac{3}{8}a$$
and  the height at which the two quarter circle intersect is
$$\frac{\sqrt{3}a}{2}$$
(forming a system of equations with the circles)

I can't think of how to calculate a small piece of the segment that remains between the intersection of the quarter circle and the small circle to find.

Can you help me?

Comment: The first steps are usually to join the points of tangency of arcs to the centres of the arcs. For example, the black circle will have at least 3 line segments, 1 to each quarter circle and 1 to the white circle.

Comment: Distance from center of small circle to bottom left corner is $a-r$ and distance from center of small circle to bottom side is $2R+r$. Distance from center of large circle to bottom left corner is $a-R$ and distance from center of large circle to bottom side is $R$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In fact, you already almost have the small circle's radius.

[image]

The height of the right triangle can be $r+\dfrac {3} {4} a$.(r: small circle's radius) also, the hypotenuse of the right triangle can be $a-r$, and the base of the triangle is $\dfrac a 2 $. You can try it from here.

Comment: hi, wow thanks, I had understood, what happened, there was something else written before, what did you change?